# How to add a redirect from the backend controller in shopware

Tags: php, shopware

I have created a plugin and after the other processes of the plugin are done i would like to redirect to a given url from a controller in the backend.

i have created a plugin that creates a documents from orders and that is working fine. however at the end of the process i would like to redirect to a url that can download or open the document that has been created. i know the url for doing so is structured like this (http://localhost:8000/backend/Order/openPdf?id=harshvalueforpdf). i am using shopware version 5.5.1 in docker on my local host.

```
 public function redirectmyurlAction()
 {
     $harsh = "9ce6b9a9cd5d469386fbb5bd692f9644";
     $search_word = $harsh;
     error_log(print_r(array('Reached redirect action'), true)."\n", 3, Shopware()->DocPath() . '/test.log');
     $this->redirect(
 array(
   'module'=> backend,
     'controller' => 'Order',
     'action' => 'openPdf?id='.$search_word,
   )
 );
 }
```

i expect that when the process reached this action the user is redirected to the created url and then it should be able to download or show the pdf. But it logs the log i put before the redirect but does not redirect. nothing is logged in errors or console. When i put the same redirect on the frontend i get the CSRFTokenValidationException which is what i expect, but it shows the redirect works there so why not in the backend.

**Update:**

After the responses,i have copied the function and modified it as below but it logs everything there and still does nothing am i missing something?

```
 public function openmyPdf($DocHarsh, $orderId)
    {
        error_log(print_r(array('Entered openmyPdf function',$DocHarsh,$orderId,$date), true)."\n", 3, Shopware()->DocPath() . '/error.log');

        $filesystem = $this->container->get('shopware.filesystem.private');
        $file = sprintf('documents/%s.pdf', basename($DocHarsh));

        if ($filesystem->has($file) === false) {
            error_log(print_r(array('Entered if statement, file doesnt exists ',$DocHarsh,$orderId,$date), true)."\n", 3, Shopware()->DocPath() . '/error.log');
            $this->View()->assign([
                'success' => false,
                'data' => $this->Request()->getParams(),
                'message' => 'File not exist',
            ]);

            return;
        }
        // Disable Smarty rendering
        $this->Front()->Plugins()->ViewRenderer()->setNoRender();
        $this->Front()->Plugins()->Json()->setRenderer(false);
        $orderModel = Shopware()->Models()->getRepository(Document::class)->findBy(['hash' =>$DocHarsh]);
        $orderModel = Shopware()->Models()->toArray($orderModel);
        $orderId = $orderModel[0]['documentId'];
        $response = $this->Response();
        $response->setHeader('Cache-Control', 'public');
        $response->setHeader('Content-Description', 'File Transfer');
        $response->setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' . $orderId . '.pdf');
        $response->setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
        $response->setHeader('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'binary');
        $response->setHeader('Content-Length', $filesystem->getSize($file));
        $response->sendHeaders();
        $response->sendResponse();
        $upstream = $filesystem->readStream($file);
        $downstream = fopen('php://output', 'wb');
        while (!feof($upstream)) {
            fwrite($downstream, fread($upstream, 4096));
        }
        error_log(print_r(array('leaving the pdf function',$DocHarsh,$orderId,$upstream,$downstream), true)."\n", 3, Shopware()->DocPath() . '/error.log');
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my own evaluation. I think the issue you are having is because this is not an action but simply a function try making it an Action and run it through the browser like the original one.

Don't forget to whitelist it.

use the class use Shopware\Components\CSRFWhitelistAware;

then

something like this

```
    /**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getWhitelistedCSRFActions()
{
    return [
        'youropenPdfActionnamewithoutthewordAction'
    ];
}
```

and also add the implements CSRFWhitelistAware to your class declaration.

Comment: This works and downloads the document ... alot more to figure out but this solves that problem.

Answer (score 3):

Please have a look at backend-controller of the order module. It should be the same case. This function is used for opening/downloading a document from the backend:
 https://github.com/shopware/shopware/blob/5.5/engine/Shopware/Controllers/Backend/Order.php#L1113

I think it might be confusing for backend users to be redirected (from the backend context) to a new blank page with a download.

Comment: i have updated the question to contain my findings after a change